# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'X' cannot be null

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entity, relational

**Hi, I've been searching on Internet and I don't understand why I get this error. I don't see any error in this code.** 
the error is:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO gallery (play_id, src) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [null, null]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'play_id' cannot be null
```

500 Internal Server Error - DBALException
1 linked Exception:
PDOException

I have a relation on play_id in gallery entity. so any gallery can related to a play.
the simplified gallery entity:

```
<?php

namespace mt\adminBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Gallery
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="gallery")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="mt\adminBundle\Entity\GalleryRepository")
 */
class Gallery
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="play_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
private $playId;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;



/**
 * Set playId
 *
 * @param integer $playId
 * @return Gallery
 */
public function setPlayId($playId)
{
    $this->playId = $playId;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get playId
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getPlayId()
{
    return $this->playId;
}

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Plays", inversedBy="galleries")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="play_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $play;

/**
 * Set play
 *
 * @param \mt\adminBundle\Entity\Plays $play
 * @return Gallery
 */
public function setPlay(\mt\adminBundle\Entity\Plays $play = null)
{
    $this->play = $play;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get play
 *
 * @return \mt\adminBundle\Entity\Plays 
 */
public function getPlay()
{
    return $this->play;
}
```

}

and the play entity:

```
<?php

namespace mt\adminBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Plays
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="plays")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="mt\adminBundle\Entity\PlaysRepository")
 */
class Plays
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Gallery", mappedBy="play")
 */
protected $galleries;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->galleries = new ArrayCollection();
}

/**
 * Add galleries
 *
 * @param \mt\adminBundle\Entity\Gallery $galleries
 * @return Plays
 */
public function addGallery(\mt\adminBundle\Entity\Gallery $galleries)
{
    $this->galleries[] = $galleries;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove galleries
 *
 * @param \mt\adminBundle\Entity\Gallery $galleries
 */
public function removeGallery(\mt\adminBundle\Entity\Gallery $galleries)
{
    $this->galleries->removeElement($galleries);
}

/**
 * Get galleries
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getGalleries()
{
    return $this->galleries;
}
```

}

I wrote this entities with the symfony Doctrine document!
my controller:

```
public function addPicAction(){
    $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
    $play = $request->request->get('galleryPlay');

        $gallery = new Gallery();
        $gallery->setPlayId($play);
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($gallery);
        $em->flush();

    $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'success!');
    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('galleries'));
}
```

the SELECT queries on this entity do very well but when i want to persist a new object of gallery into db i get the error! is there any body to help me?

Comment: what is the value of $play?

Comment: @Litz $play in controller contains the value of selected gallery that gallery related with it.

Comment: @Cerad thank you forresponce :) play_id in gallery is a field that come from play table (ID). i read the documentation of S2! shall you get me some advices to repaire my code?

Comment: Your code as stands is not repairable simply because you have not yet understood how doctrine orm works.  Once you grasp the notion of objects (as opposed to database tables) then the fix becomes trivial.